# Sketch the graph $x = t$, $y = 2t$ and $z = cos(t)$, $0\leq t \leq 4\pi$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

Sketch the graph $x = t$, $y = 2t$ and $z = cos(t)$, $0\leq t \leq 4\pi$.

I made a table:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
t& 0 & \pi & 2\pi & 3\pi & 4\pi \\ \hline
x & 0& \pi & 2\pi & 3\pi & 4\pi\\ \hline
y & 0 & 2\pi & 4\pi & 6\pi & 8\pi\\ \hline
z & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}

How would I sketch this graph?

Comment: Hint: first sketch the curve $x=t$, $y=2t$ in the $xy$-plane. Then look at the $z$-coordinate (the heights).

Comment: Look at [this plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot3D%5B%7Bt,+2+t,+Cos%5Bt%5D%7D,+%7Bt,+-10,+10%7D%5D).